# Oracle SQL - Alternative for dynamic query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure (see below) which is using dynamic query. I wanted to rewrite this procedure with out using dynamic query. How do I write the conditions below?

```
PROCEDURE DemoProcedure(p_firstname  IN VARCHAR2,
                       p_lastname   IN VARCHAR2,
                       p_phone        IN VARCHAR2
                       o_Cursor     OUT t_Cursor) IS

SQLString VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

    SQLString := 
        'SELECT * FROM 
        SCHEMA.TABLENAME_a A
        INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLENAME_b B
        ON A.ID = B.ID
        WHERE 
        A.TYPE = 1  ';

    IF p_firstname IS NOT NULL THEN
        SQLString := SQLString || ' and UPPER(A.FIRST_NAME) like UPPER( ''' || p_firstname || ''')';
    END IF;

    IF p_lastname IS NOT NULL THEN
        SQLString := SQLString || ' and UPPER(A.LAST_NAME) like UPPER( ''' || p_lastname || ''')';
    END IF;

    IF p_phone IS NOT NULL THEN
        SQLString := SQLString || ' and UPPER(A.PHONE) = ''' ||
                            p_phone || '''';
    END IF;

        SQLString := SQLString || ' order by  a.id ';

        OPEN o_Cursor FOR SQLString;

END DemoProcedure;
```

Comment: can you try the old  " and (p_phone is not null and UPPER(A.PHONE) = p_phone)"?

Comment: It would be a good idea to either store the first name and last name in upper case or define a function-based index on the columns in question.

Comment: If this is a large table it may be worthwhile having this as a dynamic query, or having multiple SQL statements rather than a single catch-all.  The reason being that Oracle will have trouble finding the right index to use if you have a set of `xx IS NULL OR xx = col_xx` statements.  The right index for a `last_name` only search will be different to a `first_name` only search.  However, you most definitely should learn how to use bind variables in your dynamic sql.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just want

```
OPEN o_cursor 
 FOR SELECT ...
      WHERE A.TYPE = 1
        AND (p_firstname IS NULL or upper(a.first_name) = upper(p_firstname))
        AND (p_lastname  IS NULL or upper(a.last_name)  = upper(p_lastname))
        AND (p_phone     IS NULL or upper(a.phone)      = p_phone)
      ORDER BY a.id
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to bother upper-casing a phone number-- do you have character data in a phone number?

Comment: sorry that was mistake while preparing the SQL for post.

Answer (score 3):

Different way writing the same SQL as @JustinCave suggested -

```
OPEN o_cursor 
 FOR SELECT ...
      WHERE A.TYPE = 1
        AND upper(a.first_name) = nvl(upper(p_firstname), upper(a.first_name))
        AND upper(a.last_name)  = nvl(upper(p_lastname),upper(a.last_name))
        AND upper(a.phone)      = nvl(p_phone,upper(a.phone))
      ORDER BY a.id
```

Comment: +1 This method may run much faster than the other answer because of some Oracle optimizations around NVL.  See [this Jonathan Lewis article](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/01/09/conditional-sql/) for details.